# how can I use the agent user defined capabilities in my azure pipelines.yml file as a variable?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, agent, azure-pipelines-yaml

Within our pipeline's we would like to set a variable based on some user defined capabilities. For example, agent-1 may store all python versions under "C:/Python" whereas agent-2 may store all python versions under "C:/Documents/Python" and a script may need to know of all the contents stemming from this folder. So, to fix this, we set some user capabilities of where it's stored.

Agent 1: `PYTHON_DIR = C:/Python`
Agent 2: `PYTHON_DIR = C:/Documents/Python`

We would like to extract these from in our azure-pipelines.yml for use in future script steps.

We initially tried using the syntax:

```
variables:
  PYTHON_EXE: $(PYTHON_DIR)\Python38\...\python.exe
```

but this simply echos out as
`$(PYTHON_DIR)\Python38\...\python.exe` even after an agent reboot.